# Spring Cloud Gateway + Nginx + Keycloak

Tags: spring, nginx, keycloak, openid-connect

I implement a mobile application and want to use OIDC. Because of that I try to define correct architecture and I have doubts which scenario is correct one.

[image]

Scenario A: Nginx keeps ssl certs and is only a reverse proxy. Mobile app displays Keycloak customized login page, gets a token and then calling apis with this token. Spring Gateway validates it with Keycloak and pass or not. This scenario simplify https connection between app and backends.

Scenario B: Spring Cloud Gateway keeps ssl certs and is a reverse proxy for Keycloak login page and Gateway for microservices that parallelly validates access token with Keycloak for api requests.

Scenario A seems for me better as Nginx takes care about SSL and I can hide rest behind and in a future when I will be adding (MVP2) web page I can serve static content via this layer as well with another location. I can't find also information if Spring Cloud Gateway should be use for static content (KeyCloak Login page and/or SPAs)